# Getting hardware info without user space tools like lshw, dmidecode

Tags: linux, hardware, embedded

I run an embedded Linux distribution without possibility to install new tools on a PC with an Asus Z790 motherboard.

In which file(s) can I find hardware info about RAM (manufacturer, model...) without `lshw`, `dmidecode` or any such commands, only using `cat` and `grep`?

Comment: Short answer, you can. `dmidecode` just parses `/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/DMI`. Provided you can ascertain the structure, you should be able to parse it with awk/sed etc. As for `lshw`, that is a bit more convoluted, but it also just parses various files under `/sys` etc, whether is parses all that you require is left as an exercise to you. Finding a working box where you can run `strace lshw` will show you what it is accessing. Again you may have to use awk/sed etc, but pretty much doable.

Comment: Thank you for helping, /sys/firmware/dmi/tables/DMI was what I was looking for!

Comment: Didn't know about this file. It didn't exist previously. Thanks.